# nodejs async.waterfall method

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

**Update 2**

Complete code listing

```
var request = require('request');
var cache = require('memory-cache');
var async = require('async');

var server = '172.16.221.190'
var user = 'admin'
var password ='Passw0rd'
var dn ='\\VE\\Policy\\Objects'

var jsonpayload = {"Username": user, "Password": password}


async.waterfall([
    //Get the API Key
    function(callback){
        request.post({uri: 'http://' + server +'/sdk/authorize/',
                json: jsonpayload,
                headers: {'content_type': 'application/json'}
            }, function (e, r, body) {
            callback(null, body.APIKey);
        })
},
    //List the credential objects
    function(apikey, callback){
        var jsonpayload2 = {"ObjectDN": dn, "Recursive": true}
        request.post({uri: 'http://' + server +'/sdk/Config/enumerate?apikey=' + apikey,
                json: jsonpayload2,
                headers: {'content_type': 'application/json'}
        }, function (e, r, body) {

            var dns = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < body.Objects.length; i++) {
                dns.push({'name': body.Objects[i].Name, 'dn': body.Objects[i].DN})
            }

            callback(null, dns, apikey);
        })

    },
    function(dns, apikey, callback){
      //  console.log(dns)

        var cb = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < dns.length; i++) {

        //Retrieve the credential
        var jsonpayload3 = {"CredentialPath": dns[i].dn, "Pattern": null, "Recursive": false}
            console.log(dns[i].dn)
        request.post({uri: 'http://' + server +'/sdk/credentials/retrieve?apikey=' + apikey,
            json: jsonpayload3,
            headers: {'content_type': 'application/json'}
        }, function (e, r, body) {
         //   console.log(body)
            cb.push({'cl': body.Classname})
            callback(null, cb, apikey);
            console.log(cb)
        });
        }


    }
], function (err, result) {
//    console.log(result)
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

**Update:**

I'm building a small application that needs to make multiple HTTP calls to a an external API and amalgamates the results into a single object or array. e.g.

1. Connect to endpoint and get auth key - pass auth key to step 2
2. Connect to endpoint using auth key and get JSON results - create an object containing summary results and pass to step 3.
3. Iterate over passed object summary results and call API for each item in the object to get detailed information for each summary line
4. Create a single JSON data structure that contains the summary and detail information.

The original question below outlines what I've tried so far!

**Original Question:**

Will the async.waterfall method support multiple callbacks?

i.e. Iterate over an array thats passed from a previous item in the chain, then invoke multiple http requests each of which would have their own callbacks.

e.g,

```
sync.waterfall([

   function(dns, key, callback){

       var cb = [];

       for (var i = 0; i < dns.length; i++) {

       //Retrieve the credential
       var jsonpayload3 = {"Cred": dns[i].DN, "Pattern": null, "Recursive": false}
           console.log(dns[i].DN)
       request.post({uri: 'http://' + vedserver +'/api/cred/retrieve?apikey=' + key,
           json: jsonpayload3,
           headers: {'content_type': 'application/json'}
       }, function (e, r, body) {
           console.log(body)
           cb.push({'cl': body.Classname})
           callback(null, cb, key);

       });
       }


   }
```

Comment: No. If you reframe the question describing what you're trying to do, what you've tried and how it fails, it's more likely that someone can give you a more helpful answer.

Comment: looks like you got lost in callback hell ..

Comment: OK so I've reframed the question with more details as to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's hope I understood your question correctly. It seems to me you want to call the api for each item in `dns` and need to know when they're done. async.waterfall is typically used when you have a chain of functions which uses the result of the preceding function. In your case I can only see that you need to use the result from all of the api-calls in one callback. And since you also want to create a new array I would use async.map.

**Update:**

If you want to make a loop inside an async.waterfall, async.each/map is the weapon of choice. The code below will call the waterfall-callback when each dns has been called.

```
async.waterfall([
  // ...,
  function(dns, apikey, callback){
    async.map(dns, function (item, next) {
      var jsonpayload3 = {
        Cred: dns[i].DN,
        Pattern: null,
        Recursive: false
      };

      request.post({
        uri: 'http://' + vedserver +'/api/cred/retrieve?apikey=' + key,
        json: jsonpayload3,
        headers: {'content_type': 'application/json'}
      }, function (e, r, body) {
        next(e, { cl: body.Classname });
      });
    },
    callback);
  }],
  function (err, result) {
    // result now looks like [{ cl: <body.Classname> }]
  });
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help here - although I'm not quite sure how your suggestion above would be implemented. I've updated my question with my complete code listing so you can see what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Sorry pasted the wrong piece of code in my update earlier - can you show me where I should add the async.map method please.

Comment: Ah, now it makes more sense. Updated the answer with how you would insert the code in your code.

Comment: Hmm Sorry Andreas, I'm still not quite with you here! I'm still not quite sure exactly where to drop this into my code!

Comment: Found a typo (the first line should be .waterfall) , but other than that, you have the line "function(dns, apikey, callback){" in your code, with the stuff that you originally posted inside. The code inside that function should be replaced by the code inside the same function in my answer. So the last function in your async.waterfall-array should contain `async.map...`.

Comment: Great new your suggestion now works perfectly - One final question: Is it possible to implement a simple filter at this line -                     **next(e, { cl: body.Classname });** that only pushes to the object if body.Classname == 'xyz'?

Comment: Andreas-Any thoughts on my previous comment, or should I create a new question here? Would it be better to re-process the resulting object to filter out the items that are not required or can it be done within the loop?

Comment: @user1513388 a new question would be better do get a more detailed answer, but `if(body.Classname === 'xyz'){ next(e, { cl: body.Classname }); } else { next(e); }` would work, but I think you'd still need to filter out null/undefined values.

Comment: Andreas, Just a question, any reason that you can think of that async.waterfall would not work from within node-webkit?

Comment: @user1513388 not really, though I haven't used node-webkit. can't see anything unusual in [the source](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L470).